# What makes a module a pragmatic module?

Tags: perl

I'm looking at the source of `base.pm` in the Perl distribution, and I don't see what distinguishes it from a "non-pragmatic" module.  If `use base` is a "pragma", is it fundamentally different in any way from `use Foo` where `Foo` is any module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no solid definition for pragma. The closest to something official is in [perlpragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpragma.html).

- They usually modify the language or the behaviour of the parser.
- Their effect is usually lexically scoped.

I personally believe those are requirements (and it seems that perlpragma does too), but core modules [vars](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?vars) and [subs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?subs) are documented to be pragmas even though their effect isn't lexically scoped.

[base](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?base) and [lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib) don't match either of the criteria. What they do is provide information to "Perl itself". I guess that also qualifies as a pragma.

I consider my module [`use syntax qw( loop );`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Syntax%3a%3aFeature%3a%3aLoop) to be pragmatic. (Shameless plug!)

Comment: Forgot to actually cover base.pm. Addressed this omission.

Comment: My comment became an answer of its own :-)

Answer (score 1):

While the name is often used in many contexts, I usually think of a pragma as something that uses the hints hash `%^H` as documented in [perldoc perlpragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpragma.html). This means that the main difference then is that the action MUST be at compile time; `use` works while `require` (not in BEGIN) doesn't. This is a key difference between a "pragmatic module" (by this definition) and other modules. By this definition none of `vars`, `subs`, `base` or `lib` are pragmas.